# Internal Server Error on deploying cron job on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine

I recently signed up and started playing with GAE for python. I was able to get their standard/flask/hello_world project. But, when I tried to upload a simple cron job following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron, I get an "Internal Server Error".

My cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: test cron
  url: /
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

The error I see

```
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
Updating config [cron]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [500]:
  Internal Server Error.

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.
```

Have I done something wrong here or is it possible that I am not eligible to add cron jobs as a free user?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but using `/` as the url for your cron job seems like a terrible idea!  Change that to `/my-cron-job` or something similar.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill that is what I originally had. I am only trying to get cron working before I write the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this problem as well, at about the same timeline. Without any changes, the deploy worked this morning, so my guess is that this was a transient server problem on Google's part.

Comment: Yes, it now works for me as well. Must have been a transient issue as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

I was just struggling with this same issue. In my case, I am using the PHP standard environment and kept receiving the '500 Internal Server Error' when I tried to publish our cron.yaml file from the Google Cloud SDK with the command:

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml --project {PROJECT_NAME}
```

To fix it, I did the following:

1. I removed all credentials from my gcloud client

   `gcloud auth revoke --all`
2. Reauthenticated within the client

   `gcloud auth login`
3. Published the cron.yaml

   `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml --project {PROJECT NAME}`

From what I can tell, the permissions in my gcloud client got out of sync which is what caused the internal server error. Hopefully that's the same case for you!